# How to change C# TextBox behavior, en masse?

Tags: c#, wpf

Our application has many TextBoxes that we disable at appropriate times.  (We set the `IsEnabled` property to `false`).  Our customer now wants the content of the TextBoxes to be non-changeable, but able to be copied.  We can do this by setting `IsReadOnly` to `true` and `IsEnabled` to `true`.

I don't really want to go to every place in the application where text boxes change state and twiddle with those settings.  How can I localize changes, such that I don't need to make a large number of edits?  Basically, I want to do something that would be almost equivalent of redefining the set part of `IsEnabled`, when the value to be set is `false`. (BTW, our customer would also like us to do some other related changes, such as setting the background color of the text box to a non-default color when "disabling" the text box.)

Comment: You should use WPF styles.

Comment: If you get the control template of the textbox, you just need to switch out what is done in the IsDisabled portion with what is done with IsReadonly. ANd by not setting the x:Key and leaving the TargetType = TextBox, this will affect your whole application. You can also do this closer to modules that need this behavior.

Comment: Are those properties you mentioned are not currently set in a code-behind?

Comment: @TYY - It sounds like control templates are the way to go.  Being new to C# and WPF, I hadn't known about them.  Now, I just need to figure out how to use them properly.  Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this would be to create a subclass of TextBox that allowed you to make these type of changes. However that requires that you change your application to replace all occurrences of `<TextBox ...` with your control:

```
<myControl:MyTextBox....
```

which doesn't really solve your problem of not wanting to change all the code.

However, it would enable you to do the other changes you mention - changing the background colour, etc. a bit easier (though that can be also achieved by overriding the default style in XAML).

Answer (score 0):

I dont really understand your question but I think it would be easiest to create a Background Worker that checks with `if ( MyTextBox.Enabled == false )` if the textbox is enabled/disabled.